# How to write unit test for http request with Alamofire?

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, alamofire

My app is using Alamofire to send http request and wanna write some unit test for this part. I have created some json file as response. How can I block the Alamofire request and let Alamofire to return the content in json file as response? Can we use method swizzling to replace the function？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a framework like OHHTTPStubs to stub you network requests or make real network requests. In either case, `XCTest` has a variety of methods for asynchronous waiting, like `XCTExpectation`s.

Answer (score 2):

This is how you wait for some asynchronous callbacks. This is bare minimum test. You can improve it more for your test requirement

```
func testCheckThatTheNetworkResponseIsEqualToTheExpectedResult() {

    //expected result 
    let expectedResult: [String:Any] = ["data":"somedata","order_number":2]

    let expectations = expectation(description: "The Response result match the expected results")

    if let requestUrl = URL(string: "some url to fetch data from") {

        let request = Alamofire.request(requestUrl, method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: nil)
        request.responseJSON(completionHandler: { (response) in
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let result):
                //do the checking with expected result
                //AssertEqual or whatever you need to do with the data
                //finally fullfill the expectation
                expectations.fulfill()
            case .failure(let error):
                //this is failed case
                XCTFail("Server response failed : \(error.localizedDescription)")
                expectations.fulfill()
            }
        })

        //wait for some time for the expectation (you can wait here more than 30 sec, depending on the time for the response)
        waitForExpectations(timeout: 30, handler: { (error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Failed : \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }

        })
    }

}
```

Comment: This gives error as "Unable to update application state promptly for Application" at waitForExpectations.